# determine if the following set is closed, bounded and compact

Tags: real-analysis

$A = \{a\cos(x) + b\sin(x)\, \colon \, x \in \mathbb{R}, (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \}$

$B = \{a+bx+cx^2 \, \colon \, x \in [0,1], \, a,b,c \in \mathbb{R},\, a^2+b^2+c^2 =1\}$

For $A$, if assume a sequence $a_n = a\cos(n) + b\sin(n)$, does the limit exist?
I think that there should be a bound on $a\cos x+b\sin x$, but I don't know the exact bound.

For $B$, I was totally lost.

Comment: Seeing your earlier posts, it seems you haven't reached that tutorial page yet. This site uses MathJax. [*Here*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that in both sets $\;x,a,b,c\;$ are taken over all possibilities in $\;\Bbb R\;$ and none is constant?

Comment: @Tanny Liu If $x=0$ and $a$ vary among the reals, you get $A=\mathbb{R}$. Also, I have not checked the details but it seems to me that $B$ is a closed intervals in the reals. So both $A,B$ are closed, and $B$ is also bounded and compact. Do you want $a,b$ and $a,b,c$ to vary? or to have constant values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $A$: Suppose $x=0$, $\{acos(0)+bsin(0)=a, a\in R\}=R\subset A$, so $A=R$.

$B$: Consider $C=\{a,b,c, a^2+b^2+c^2=1\}$ and $I=[0,1]$, let $f:R^4\rightarrow R$ defined $f(a,b,c,x)=a+bx+cx^2$, $f$ is continue and $B=f(C\times I)$, since $C\times I$ is compact, its image by a continuous map is compact, so $B$ is compact.

Comment: The hint for A is quite useful. Thank you.